# I want to do indexed loop for each th:each loop

Tags: html, thymeleaf

for example,

```
<div class="product-price" th:each="price, priceStat : ${itemPrice0}" th:if="${priceStat.index<1}">
            <span><a>$</a><a th:text="${price.normal}"></a></span>
</div>
```

i want to repeat it for itemPrice0, itemPrice1, itemPrice2, ...
then there will be loop for

```
<div class="product-price" th:each="price, priceStat : ${itemPrice0}" th:if="${priceStat.index<1}">
            <span><a>$</a><a th:text="${price.normal}"></a></span>
</div>
<div class="product-price" th:each="price, priceStat : ${itemPrice1}" th:if="${priceStat.index<1}">
            <span><a>$</a><a th:text="${price.normal}"></a></span>
</div>
<div class="product-price" th:each="price, priceStat : ${itemPrice2}" th:if="${priceStat.index<1}">
            <span><a>$</a><a th:text="${price.normal}"></a></span>
</div>
```

is there any way to do it in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

```
<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, 2)}">
  <div class="product-price" th:each="price, priceStat : ${itemPrice__${i}__}" th:if="${priceStat.index<1}">
    <span><a>$</a><a th:text="${price.normal}"></a></span>
  </div>
</th:block>
```

(However, this is bad design. Instead, I would recommend adding a `List<List<ItemPrice>>` to the model instead -- and looping over both lists.)

Comment: I tried concatenating methods, but what really needed to do is using underbar(_)s, which i never thought of. thank you! and i will try better design with List<List<ItemPrice>>.